# Proving the independence of the set $\{\cos x,\sin x\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading a book about linear algebra and there was the following saying:

> The set $\{\cos x,\sin x\}$ is independent.

They didn't prove it so I decided I should prove it. I would like to find $\lambda_{1,2}\in\mathbb{R}$ so $\lambda_{1}\cdot \cos x + \lambda_{2} \cdot \sin x = 0$. But how can I continue from that? I can assume that $\lambda_1 \neq 0$ in order to get $\tan x=-\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda{1}}$, but how to prove that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Choose particular value of $x$, for example choose $x=0$. You should be able to solve one of the unknown directly.
- Can you choose another value of $x$ to make $\cos x = 0$?

Comment: I do understand that logic, and I also thought about it. Although the proof does not feels to be valid for me.

Comment: why not? can you elaborate on your doubt?

Comment: As I understand, you suggest to choose $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and to decide that it will not prove $cosx=0$ for that $x$. but there are infinite values in $\mathbb{R}$, what if one of them will solve it? I'm trying to find a proof for $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: We have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda_1 \cos x + \lambda_2 \sin x = 0$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are fixed for every single possible values of $x$, hence you can pick particular real value of $x$ and the relationship should remain true.

Comment: But for example if $\lambda_{i}=1$ we can insert $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ so we get zero. So we found $x$ and $\lambda_{i}\neq0$ so the equation is true. Does it not prove that they are dependent?

Comment: You found a non-zero solution for $x=\frac{3\pi}4$, but for this particular solution of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, if you change another value of $x$, it doesn't hold, hence the proposed $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is not the right one. We have to find $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ that hold for every single value of $x$. That is for your solution of $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, if we let $x=0$, we get a contradiction of $1=0$, hence, the $\lambda$ that found is not the right coefficient.

Comment: So I'll insert $x=0,0.5\pi$. I will get two equations which dependent on $a,b$ (are they the same?). From one equation I'll get $a=0,b\n\mathbb{R}$ and from the other equation I'll get $b=0,a\n\mathbb{R}$. Can I combine it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87453/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-ttajta4).

Answer (score 0):

In view of your linear equation, let $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$. Then the linear equation gives $\tan x = -\lambda_2/\lambda_1$. But this would need to hold for each such $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If any one of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ is non-zero, the $LHS$ will be periodic with period $2\pi$ while the $RHS$ is not. Therefore, $\lambda_{1,2}=0$.

Comment: The constant function is periodic with period $2 \pi$.

Comment: No, it is not periodic with $2\pi$.

Comment: Let $f(x)=c$ for a constant $c$. Then we have that $f(x+p)=c=f(x)$, so it is periodic with period $p$. Now let $p=2\pi$...

Comment: Period is the smallest positive number $t$ such that $f(x+t)=f(x)$. While constants are periodic, their period is not defined. You can take the period of the zero function as $1$. Is the $lHS$ periodic with $1$ for non-zero $\lambda$?

Comment: @subham You can take the period of zero function as any $\epsilon>0$. $1$ would not be a period if we consider it smallest

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to say. You can take the period of zero function as $1$. Is the $LHS$ periodic with $1$ for non-zero $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, it does not have a smallest period, but I'd still call it periodic. But it's just the matter of definition, I guess.

Comment: I am not objecting to calling it periodic, but the period is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try a proof by contradiction and follow the same approach you give here. The expression you have for $ \tan x $ is the contradiction. (It implies that the function is constant).